# Will HITL train a pre-defined processor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

When setting up a HITL for a pre-defined process i.e. Bank Statement processor, when a labeler helps improve the data identified in a particular document will this action help improve the model for the processor?

If not, what is the recommended alternative to train a pre-defined model?

Answer (score 0):

<s>There currently isn't a feature to improve the models for this type of processor, but you can ask your Google Cloud Account Manager (if you have one) to reach out to the product team to discuss the options.</s>

If you don't currently have a Google Cloud Account Manager, you can reach out to the sales team from the [Contact Us page](https://cloud.google.com/contact)

The [Uptraining](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/training-overview#uptrain) feature is now in public preview that allows improving the pre-trained specialized processors.

This can use Human in the Loop output data in the [`Document` object format](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) to create customized processor versions trained with your own data.

Follow this tutorial to get started: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/uptrain-processor